# Looking to use Machine Learning to automate customer service. How do I apply Machine Learning to generate text replies to customers?

Tags: machine-learning

The questions is pretty self-explanatory. But for more background information, I am working in a medium sized company. We have a number of customer support requests about similar bugs, similar issues, etc. We use templates to reply to many emails.

How would I get started applying Machine Learning to this process to automate replies? I would like to suggest a text reply to our support reps that they can make minimal edits to and send off.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume in this answer you have some background in machine learning. I assume also a slight simplification of the problem, where you just want to match an e-mail from customer with an existing bug/issue/category (then you could bring up all replies from support).

Here are some good heuristics / things to keep in mind when trying to apply machine learning:

1. Understand data
2. Understand customer of solution
3. Try something simple first
4. 20% of effort will brings 80% of results (known as Pareto principle)
5. Spend substantial time on developing framework/dataset to test solution
6. Best machine learning solutions are often ones that empower human, not replace him
7. Often accuracy comes from different other part of the system than model (like for instance let user tag his e-mail)

My general advice would be first try to focus on some common issues/bugs (that are let's say target of top 50% e-mails), collect dataset and evaluate if you can get some practical results. Try to solve problem of sort "bring correct e-mail template in top5 results".

For actual model that can solve such a problem, this is very open ended and there is no good answer. My intuition is that there will be words that are very descriptive of some common issues/bugs, and for rare issues/bugs we won't be able to get any useful accuracy (unless using something sophisticated, which we cannot use before trying something simple and gaining intuition about the problem).

Naive Bayes tends to work surprisingly well in the NLP context and is also easily interpretable. Here are some steps you could follow:

- Do some general data analysis: what is distribution of number of emails per bug. Do the emails for given bug even look similar?
- If the previous step has promising outcome try assembling dataset
- Now you could try to use a model like NB (there are easy to follow examples in scikit-learn, for instance http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/mlcomp_sparse_document_classification.html#example-text-mlcomp-sparse-document-classification-py )

  - Keep in mind NB should be cross validated
  - For metric I assume you want to use top5 and top1 simple accuracy
  - In scikit-learn you can very easily swap classifiers.
  - Definitely look into words that are strong predictors and gain some intuition about problem.
  - If you decide to evaluate on rarer classes it might be too sparse for such straightforward treatment as multiclass classification. You might want to look into similarity search or clustering, but I wouldn't focus on this at this stage.
- Show your results to end user of the solution. Is that helpful? How much time would that save?
- Given first results - do you want to invest into making it production ready? Do you think you can improve accuracy or is it too hard?

This answer is very high level, but it is hard to suggest a more complicated and justified solution without more information (like trying simple model first) :)